# Is there a name for this metric: TN / (TN + FN)?

Tags: precision-recall, confusion-matrix

Given a confusion matrix, there's all kind of metrics: Accuracy, Precision, Recall/Sensitivity, Specificity.

[image]

But I haven't seen any name for the ratio between the TN (True Negative) and the sum of TN + FN (False Negative):
$$
\frac{TN}{TN + FN}
$$

Is there a name for it? If not - why isn't it important enough to have a name?

Comment: There's a nice overview of the terminology on the right hand side of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be the [Negative predictive value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values).

Comment: [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called **Negative Predictive Value** (NPV) which measures the accuracy of negative predictions. You can read more about it on wikipedia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix